# Currently how many types of peethas are there in India?

Tags: advaita, shakti

In India how many **different types of peethas** such as shakti peethas,  Advaita peethas etc., are there now?

Comment: But there is a lot of difference between Shakti Pithas and Advaita Pithas .. the former are of divine nature and origin where as the later are made by human beings

Comment: 74 simhasana-adhipathis were established by Sri Ramaunjacharya 1000 years ago.. of that ~40 today

Answer (score 1):

According to manthanbhairava tantra-kumari khanda there are total of 64 such places classified as follow-8 pithas,8 upapithas,8 kestras,8 upakestras,8 samdoha,8 upasamdoha,8 melapaka,8 upamelapaka.Same kind of clasdification folow by buddhist cakrasambara tradition but they have 72 pithas.
Note:the piths known as ancient times may not be same as founded in modern age.